# Dimming LED lights with PWM, driver quite far from LEDs, noise considerations

Tags: led, pwm, emc

There were a few questions like this before, however I haven't found ultimate answer yet.

I'm going to drive LED lights in my house with multi-channel driver (PWM controller + MOSFET Transistors), which is going to be located in a basement.

At this time cables are already plastered inside walls, they are 4 x 1.5mm^2 each (for RGB). Some of them are 10m long, some of them are 50m long. There is no option to split the driver into single channel drivers and put them close to LED bulbs, so I'm stuck with this solution.

The target lights varies in power, some of them are going to take 300mA, some of them 5A or maybe 10A.

The PWM frequency is going to be somewhere between 200Hz and XXkHZ.

I'm worried, that this solution is going to cause serious interference.

What devices are going to be interfered and how badly?
FM Radios?
GSM / 3G / LTE Signal?
WiFi Signal?
Any others?

What other problems should I consider?

How can I prevent unwanted side effects?

I have also seen this solution for some professional home-automation systems, like ABB 'Light Controller, 1-10 V, x-fold, 16 A, MDRC LR/S x.16.1, 2CDG 110 08x R0011'

Answer (score 1):

The inductance of the wires will create voltage spikes -- be careful for your drivers. In any case, they may not be able to regulate the current in a stable way with large series inductances.

Likely AM and TV will be the worst affected (all below 100 MHz), but cheap radios may get swamped with the interference.

Is the reason you are using PWM because you want precise colour ? If you can accept small colour variations, then DC (variable current) drive would be much better as far as emissions are concerned.